# Pycharm edu terminal plugin missing

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, ide, pycharm

First time posting, let me know how I can improve my questions.

I have installed PyCharm Edu 3.0 and Anaconda 3 on an older laptop. I am attempting to access the embedded terminal in the IDE and I am unable to launch it.

I have searched through similar questions here and the JetBrains docs, and the common knowledge seems to be installing the "Terminal" Plugin. My version of PyCharm does not have this plugin, and I am unable to find it in the JetBrains plugin list or community repositories.

If anyone has experienced this before or knows where I am going wrong attempting to launch the terminal I would appreciate the feedback.

Comment: That's a rather old version of pycharm (Oct 2013 apparently), most docs are referring to newer versions. Any reason for which you don't install a recent one?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories > Search and Install Native Terminal

This will install a terminal which will use the Windows Native terminal.

A small black button will appear on the tool bar.

If you did not enable the tool bar, here is the trick: View | toolbar
check this toolbar option and the cmd button will be shown on the bar

Answer (score -1):

Click preferences and choose plugin. Next click install Jetbrains plugin and choose Command line Tool Support. I hope this will help you

Comment: The "Command line tool support" plugin is not the terminal plugin and does not provide any terminal functionality.